# Spring Batch - Hibernate & Hikari: SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, azure-sql-database, hikaricp

I have a spring batch application that uses Azure SQL server, it runs without any issues and updates the Database for a most part however I am getting the following error occasionally

```
2021-10-04T14:29:17,685 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] WARN  SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2021-10-04T14:29:17,685 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
2021-10-04T14:29:17,686 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR TaskletStep: Rolling back with transaction in unknown state
2021-10-04T14:29:17,687 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR TransactionTemplate: Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
```

I am using the below dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is my **Database configuration**

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<!-- HikariCP Database bean -->
<bean id="demoDataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>

<!-- HikariConfig config that is fed to above dataSource -->
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://demo.database.windows.net:1433;database=sqldb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;" />
    <property name="username" value="user1" />
    <property name="password" value="p@ssword1" /
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />
```

Below is my **job-definition.xml**

```
<!-- Simple step used as parent of all steps in item recode -->
<bean id="simpleStep" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleStepFactoryBean"
      abstract="true">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="startLimit" value="10" />
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<batch:job id="readStudentFromKafka"  incrementer="incrementer">
    <batch:step id="kafkaSSReadSingleStep" parent="simpleStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk
                    reader="StudentStgReader"
                    processor="StudentStgProcessor"
                    writer="StudentStgWriter"
                    commit-interval="10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="StudentStgReader" class="com.demo.batch.jobs.kafka.StudentStgReader" />

<bean id="StudentStgProcessor" class="com.demo.batch.jobs.kafka.StudentStgProcessor" />

<bean id="StudentStgWriter" class="com.demo.batch.jobs.kafka.StudentStgWriter">
    <constructor-arg ref="hibernateItemWriter"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobExplorer"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="demoDataSource"
      p:tablePrefix="BATCH_"/>
```

Below is my **Spring Batch Writer class**

```
public class StudentStgWriter implements ItemWriter<List<Student>> {
    private HibernateItemWriter<Student> hibernateItemWriter;

    public StudentStgWriter(HibernateItemWriter<Student> hibernateItemWriter) {
        this.hibernateItemWriter = hibernateItemWriter;

        System.out.println("Hibernate Writer instance is created..: " + hibernateItemWriter.hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends List<Student>> items) throws Exception {
        try {
            for (List<Student> StudentStg : items) {
                hibernateItemWriter.write(StudentStg);
            }

            hibernateItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
            System.out.println(String.format("StudentStg Processing Completed %s", new LocalDateTime()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this issue? Is there a way for us to have retry logic implemented in the above **Spring Batch Writer class**

```
2021-10-04T14:29:17,685 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] WARN  SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2021-10-04T14:29:17,685 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
2021-10-04T14:29:17,686 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR TaskletStep: Rolling back with transaction in unknown state
2021-10-04T14:29:17,687 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR TransactionTemplate: Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
```

Comment: May you print the executed SQL? It seems something related to the Query; moreover try to add `ssl=require` to the connection url; so it becomes `<property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://demo.database.windows.net:1433;database=sqldb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;ssl=require" />`

Comment: could you explain how "ssl=require" will fix this?